# Magento 2.3.3 - Date format issue in admin area with different locale

Tags: admin-panel, magento2.3.3, datepicker, locale-translation

I tried to edit the product special price date from admin with different `locale` and it showing issue with date format.

It is working properly with `en_US` locale. When I switch the locale to `nl_NL`, the day and year changed each other.

**For example** : If I selected `30/01/2020` and `01/01/2021` date in `en_US` locale.

It shows `20-01-2030` and `21-01-2001` in `nl_NL` locale. Also, I can correct the date and save again with `nl_NL`. It shows the same issue after save.

Comment: You are not alone in this; we're experiencing this issue too! For now we're just forcing everyone to use the en_US backend locale, but it isn't optimal.. This bugreport claims it should've been fixed; https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6858 and here's a new one specifically for nl_NL locale; https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25182

Comment: Same issue for me on 2.3.4 commerce with en_GB locale I receive a error, with en_US it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using RTL language then try to use this.
it was very useful for me
https://github.com/menacoders/rtl-datepicker-magento2
it will help you to solve RTL datepicker issue in magneto 2 dashboard.